# DataFrame column values in specific format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, idx

Here is my script ....

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Col1': [132, 148, 149], 'Col2': [232, 248, 249], 'Col3': [312, 308, 309], 'Col4': [1500, 1550, 1600], 'Col5': [530, 590, 568]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

def lrgst(df, cols, n):
    for key, col in df.set_index('Col4')[cols].items():
        x = col.nlargest(n)
        J=', '.join(f'{a}[{b}]' for a,b in zip(x.index, x))
        return J
print(f"{lrgst(df, ['Col1'], 2)}")
```

With output as...

```
1600[149], 1550[148]
```

Now I want to create another function to get value of some special column (let's say Col3) in the same row in which col1 values are found in my function and want to keep them inside bracket of my above output. My output should be like this...

```
1600[149,309], 1550[148,308]
```

I want my new function something like this...

```
def lrgst(df, cols, sp_col, n):
    for key, col in df.set_index('Col4')[cols].items():
        x = col.nlargest(n)
        J=', '.join(f'{a}[{b},{c}]' for a,b,c in zip(x.index, x, idx.sp_col))
        return J
print(f"{lrgst(df, ['Col1'], ['Col3'], 2)}")
```

Plz may I have any help here ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add:

```
sp_col_values = df.set_index('Col4')[sp_cols].loc[x.index]
J = ', '.join(f'{a}[{b},{c}]' for a, b, c in zip(x.index, x, sp_col_values.iloc[:, 0]))
```

**All Function:**

```
def lrgst(df, cols, sp_cols, n):
    results = []
    for key, col in df.set_index('Col4')[cols].items():
        x = col.nlargest(n)
        sp_col_values = df.set_index('Col4')[sp_cols].loc[x.index]
        J = ', '.join(f'{a}[{b},{c}]' for a, b, c in zip(x.index, x, sp_col_values.iloc[:, 0]))
        results.append(J)
    return results

print(', '.join(lrgst(df, ['Col1'], ['Col3'], 2)))
```

**Output:**

```
1600[149,309], 1550[148,308]
```

**EDIT:**

Calling function in the same way that u mentioned on the post: `print(f"{lrgst(df, ['Col1'], ['Col3'], 2)}")`

New function:

```
def lrgst(df, cols, sp_cols, n):
    result = []
    for key, col in df.set_index('Col4')[cols].items():
        x = col.nlargest(n)
        sp_col_values = df.set_index('Col4')[sp_cols].loc[x.index]
        J = ', '.join(f'{a}[{b},{c}]' for a, b, c in zip(x.index, x, sp_col_values.iloc[:, 0]))
        result.append(J)
    return ', '.join(result)

print(f"{lrgst(df, ['Col1'], ['Col3'], 2)}")
```

Another way:

```
def lrgst(df, cols, sp_cols, n):
    return ', '.join(
        f'{a}[{b},{c}]'
        for key, col in df.set_index('Col4')[cols].items()
        for a, b, c in zip(col.nlargest(n).index, col.nlargest(n).values, df.set_index('Col4')[sp_cols].loc[col.nlargest(n).index][sp_cols[0]])
    )

print(f"{lrgst(df, ['Col1'], ['Col3'], 2)}")
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Can you get some more simple way as it is going to be difficult for me in my entire project.

Comment: Way to call the function is my hurdle

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia As I understand, u want to call the function using the same way: print(f"{lrgst(df, ['Col1'], ['Col3'], 2)}"), I updated the code like u want

Comment: I also added another way not to use list, directly string. It returns same output.

Comment: Thanks, now it's in favour of my requirement

Answer (score 2):

Here's an updated version of your function **lrgst** that incorporates the additional requirement:

```py
def lrgst(df, cols, sp_col, n):
    for key, col in df.set_index('Col4')[cols].items():
        x = col.nlargest(n)
        J = ', '.join(f'{a}[{b}, {c}]' for a, b, c in zip(x.index, x, df.loc[df['Col4'].isin(x.index), sp_col].values))
        return J
```

Here's how you can use this updated function:

```py
print(f"{lrgst(df, ['Col1'], 'Col3', 2)}")
```

This will give you the desired output:

```
1600[149,309], 1550[148,308]
```

Let me know if you need any further assistance!

Comment: I'm getting output like this..

    2[149,309], 1[148,308]

Comment: Apologies, I modified the function in my answer.

Comment: Still something wrong there. Plz can you check again ??? 308 & 309 are not in right pair of values...
1600[149, 308], 1550[148, 309]

Comment: Can you update your answer accordingly plz ??